# Validity vs. tautology in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I have been starting my studies on predicate logic, and in a paper I'm reading it is said not all the valid sentences are tautologies.

An example of such a sentence is given:

> $\exists x Q \leftrightarrow \lnot \forall x \lnot Q$.

Now in what sense it might be said that it is not a tautology?

I thank you for your answers beforehand.

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953814/according-to-language-proof-and-logic-a-a-is-not-a-tautology-why-not?rq=1

Comment: You have to check the definition of *tautology*: usually, it is defined in the context of propositional logic. For FOL, a formula is a tautology if it is  obtainable from a tautology of propositional logic by replacing (uniformly) each sentence symbol by a formula of the first-order language.This is not the case with the formula above, that we can get from the propositional $P \leftrightarrow R$, that is not taut.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't $\forall x \forall y ~ P(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \forall y~P(y,x)$ a tautology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509477/why-isnt-forall-x-forall-y-px-y-rightarrow-forall-x-forall-ypy-x)