# Is $\forall xP(x) \vee \neg \forall yP(y)$ a tautology in FOL?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I am claiming that  $$\forall xP(x) \vee \neg \forall yP(y)$$ is a tautology, since if we denote $\varphi = \forall xP(x)$ and we know that $(\varphi \vee \neg\varphi)$ is a tautology in propositional logic and is equivalent to our given formula then the given formula is a tautology.

However, my text says that it is not a tautology.

I can't find a way to show that this formula is indeed not a tautology.

Comment: Every propositional-logic tautology (which you've correctly argued this to be) is automatically a first-order validity (first-order tautology). P.S. This question is not a duplicate of the above suggested link.

Comment: @ryang Note that the two disjuncts are **not** actually negations of each other here - the variable change, while trivial to us, does prevent this from being a (substitution instance of a) propositional tautology.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes of course; thanks for the correction! This given formula isn't a propositional-logic tautology but is certainly an FOL validity (FOL tautology).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$\forall xP(x) \vee \neg \forall yP(y)$$

The given formula has truth-functional form $$A∨¬B,$$ so is *not* a (propositional-logic) tautology. Because it is equivalent to $$\forall xP(x) \vee \neg \forall xP(x),$$ it certainly is a first-order validity. You might call it a "first-order tautology".

While some FOL texts consider "validity" and "tautology" synonymous, your textbook is [using a strict definition of "tautology"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4509499/21813) referring specifically to propositional-logic tautologies.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understood, because the given formula is equivalent to $$\forall xP(x) \vee \neg \forall xP(x)$$ we can say that it is equivalent to propositional-logic tautology and therefore is FOL tautology ?

Comment: I didn’t actually explain why it’s a validity. Your indirect reasoning isn’t wrong.